# How to Rename DBContext in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-6

I had an issue with EF not pulling in the Foreign Key relationships when doing an Update Model From Database. So I just deleted the .edmx file and regenerated it. The problem is that my context type was named InventoryMgmtContext, and now I am getting the error

```
The type of namespace InventoryMgmtContext could not be found.
```

Where/how can you rename the context?

Comment: Open your edmx file, right click on the database diagram empty area and click properties. This is where you should be able to find new name for your dbContext and you may be able to change it.

Comment: @KiranVarsani that is what I would've thought....but it wasn't clear. After trial and error, I have found that you need to change the EntityContainerName property, which equates to the Context Name.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. Open the EDMX diagram, right click the background, and click "Properties":

[image]

2. Change the `Entity Container Name` value to the name you want:

[image]

3. Save the EDMX.